# How to write IF ELSE statements in ASP.NET inside document?

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net, .net

I'm having some problem with using `if` statements in ASP.NET C# html documents.

I want to do what is below in `PHP`, in `asp`.

```
<?php if(1==1){ ?>
  <h1>Hellow World!</h1>
<?php }else{ ?>
  <h1>Bye World!</h1
<?php } ?>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Create an `.aspx` page?

Comment: Although you can certainly do inline C#, it's probably to be noted that in my experience developers don't do that nearly as much as you might think. To accomplish what you want, a developer might use Panels and then hide the panels from code behind. It keeps the logic separated from the markup better.

Comment: No one is going to upvote it, because the answer can be found by searching for 2 seconds - https://www.google.co.uk/#q=asp.net+if+else+statement+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tags" for embebed C# code in ASP.NET web pages is `<% CODE %>`.
If you need to print some values you would use `<%= CODE RETURNING VALUE %>`

Here is the literal transcripted fo you write in php:

```
    <% if(1==1){ %>
      <h1>Hellow World!</h1>
    <% }else{ %>
      <h1>Bye World!</h1>
    <% } %>
```

But you can get the same output with this:

```
<%= 1 == 1 ? "<h1>Hellow World!</h1>" : "<h1>Bye World!</h1>" %>
```

OR

```
<h1><%= 1 == 1 ? "Hellow" : "Bye" %> World!</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <% if(1==1){ %>
      <h1>Hellow World!</h1>
    <% }else{ %>
      <h1>Bye World!</h1
    <% }  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<% if(1==1){ %>
  <h1>Hellow World!</h1>
<% }else{ %>
  <h1>Bye World!</h1
<% } %>
```